# In SSRS fill every row with value in matrix

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I created a report in Report Builder and my users would like to export it to excel to do row operations.  They are asking for every  row to be completely filled in with data. As it is now, the grouping columns have only data on the first line and then are blank for the rest.

I have tried not grouping it at all. But that does not work.

It looks similar to this.

**Style**                   -----------------  **Size**
Classic Chique -----     Small
-----------------------       Medium
--------------------------Large

Modern Chique----   XSmall

I would want it to say "Classic Chique" On every line pertaining to that style and "Modern  Chique" on every line pertaining to it.

However I do not know how to do that on Report Studios.

Any suggestions?

( I can not post a picture because I do not have a good enough reputation)

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you are talking about.  If you have instances where inner joins are getting rid of some row operations you can change them to left joins and always include the row values in the TSQL.  I hope this is what you are reffering to and here is a simple example of how I would handle an issue where there was a person with no orders in a matrix environment.

```
declare @Person Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

insert into @Person values ('Brett'),('Sean'),('Chad'),('Michael');

declare @Orders table ( OrderID int identity, PersonID int, Desciption varchar(32), Amount int);

insert into @Orders values (1, 'Shirt', 20),(2, 'Shirt', 22),(3, 'Shirt', 20);

Select 
    person
,   OrderID
,   Desciption
,   Amount
from @Person p
    join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID

-- versus showing the person with no orders in a matrix environment where 
-- the 'Person' should be shown on the row

Select
    person
,   isnull(OrderID, '') as OrderID
,   isnull(Desciption, 'N/A') as Description
,   isnull(Amount, '0') as Amount
from @Person p
    left join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID
```

EDIT:

If you are describing the row repeating I would just have that row NOT be in a parent group of anything as that appears what is happening.  If you are wanting to repeat a group header every row, that makes it not a grouping anymore.  Just remove the grouping from 'Row Groups' and instead put that column name in the line item detail.

1. In VS when you are in 'Design' (small tab above central design area) move to bottom left under 'Row Groups'
2. Click your grouping ABOVE '=(Details)'.  Generally it is the name of the column you are gropuing on.
3. Right Click > DELETE
4. You are prompted 'Delete Group' with two choices.
5. Select 'Delete Group Only'
6. This should remove the grouping logic (which you seem not to want) and keep the column.  Depending on your dataset you now should have the data repeat every row.

Comment: I edited my post so that the question is more clear. I see that it was hard to understand. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: See my updates it appears from what you are describing you have a header grouping there that you do not want.

Comment: For some reason that did not work. I tried that first. In the end you must concatenate all the fields you want to show in the "Group Properties" Expression field.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I made one group which I couldn't avoid, because I needed to break pages between each member of that group, but then I made a second group under it and grouped on all of the other items I wanted to show, in the order I wanted to show them. That had the effect of creating one line with the sum for each combination. So far so good. Then I added a column to the right of the column containing the first field in the group, but I made it to the right and OUTSIDE the group. I repeated this for each value included in the grouping values. The result was that each value showed once on each line, making it a good candidate for export to Excel.

(And we all know that the finance types will ALWAYS export what we give them to Excel!)

I wish I could include the rdl code but I am concerned with sharing any work product.

Joey